# How functions is going to call

Tags: elixir

I am trying to configure it out, how fibonacci work and have following code

```
defmodule FibSolver do

    def fib(n) do

        fib_calc(n)

    end

  defp fib_calc(0) do
    IO.puts "Zero"
    0
  end

  defp fib_calc(1) do
    IO.puts "One"
    1
  end

  defp fib_calc(n) do
        IO.puts n
    fib_calc(n-1) + fib_calc(n-2)
  end

end
```

As output I've got

```
iex(10)> FibSolver.fib(5)
5
4
3
2
One
Zero

One
2
One
Zero
3
2
One
Zero
One
5
```

Until the newline, I can imagine how it works, but after then I am very confuse.

Comment: Is that blank line actually in your output or did you insert it?

Comment: Yes, I did insert the blank line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the function is not recursive, the recursion goes left to right. We can substitute the values to determine which function is being executed and which value is printed at that point.

`fib(2)` does not recurse on the 3rd clause, so the output is as you expect.
Output:

```
2
One
Zero
```

Substitutions:

```
fib(2)
                          # Output 2
fib(1) + fib(0)
                          # Output One
1      + fib(0)
       i                  # Output Zero
1      + 0
1
```

`fib(3)` will recurse on the 3rd clause, which causes your unexpected output:

Output:

```
3
2
One
Zero
One
```

Substitutions:

```
fib(3)
                           # Output 3
fib(2) + fib(1)
                           # Output 2
fib(1) + fib(0) + fib(1)
                           # Output One
1      + fib(0) + fib(1)
                           # Output Zero
1      +  0     + fib(1)
                           # Output One
1      +  0     + 1
```

If you perform the same substitution for `fib(5)` (I'm not including it here because it would be quite long) you will see that the output matches yours.

**EDIT**

`fib(4)` as requested:

Output:

```
4
3
2
One
Zero
One
2
One
Zero
```

Substitutions:

```
fib(4)
                                            # Output 4
fib(3) + fib(2)
                                            # Output 3
fib(2) + fib(1) + fib(2)
                                            # Output 2
fib(1) + fib(0) + fib(1) + fib(2)
                                            # Output One
1      + fib(0) + fib(1) + fib(2)
                                            # Output Zero
1      + 0      + fib(1) + fib(2)
                                            # Output One
1      + 0      + 1      + fib(2)
                                            # Output 2
1      + 0      + 1      + fib(1) + fib(0)
                                            # Output One
1      + 0      + 1      + 1      + fib(0)
                                            # Output Zero
1      + 0      + 1      + 1      + 0
```

Comment: Why is not going to call recursively?

Comment: @zero_coding I don't understand the question, it does call recursively?

Comment: I mean 'fib_calc(n-1)' is a recursive call. So the function is going to call them self until they reach 0 or 1 right?

Comment: Can you make please substitution for 4 you too?

Comment: I've added 4. Hopefully that will help you with the general pattern.